# Creating Bigtable replica cluster gives metric error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

Playing with the newest Bigtable feature: cross-region replication.

I've created an instance and a replica cluster in a different region with this snippet:

```
gcloud bigtable instances create ${instance_id} \
        --cluster=${cluster_id} \
        --cluster-zone=${ZONE} \
        --display-name=${cluster_id} \
        --cluster-num-nodes=${BT_CLUSTER_NODES} \
        --cluster-storage-type=${BT_CLUSTER_STORAGE} \
        --instance-type=${BT_TYPE} \
        --project=${PROJECT_ID}

gcloud beta bigtable clusters create ${cluster_id} \
        --instance=${instance_id} \
        --zone=${ZONE} \
        --num-nodes=${BT_CLUSTER_NODES} \
        --project=${PROJECT_ID}
```

The instance created successfully, but creating the replica cluster gave me an error: `ERROR: (gcloud.beta.bigtable.clusters.create) Metric 'bigtable.googleapis.com/ReplicationFromEUToNA' not defined in the service configuration.`

However the cluster created and replication worked.

I know this is currently beta, but do I need to change my setup script, or this is something on GCP side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm that this is an issue on the GCP side. As you noted this is happening after replication is set up, so there should be no practical impact to you.

We have a ticket open to fix the underlying issue, which is purely around reporting the successful copy to our own internal monitoring. Thanks for the report!